# jQuery check all using this/parent

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following code to check multiple checkboxes:

```
$('.checkall-label').click(function(){
   $('.checkbox-wrapper .checkall-input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

The above code works fine.

But I have multiple groups of checkboxes so I want find checkboxes within the checkall-label parent div only, and then check the specific group of check boxes only like so:

```
$('.checkall-label').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.checkbox-wrapper .checkall-input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

But this code isn't working, could anyone tell me where I'm going wrong? Thanks

Comment: Please click `[<>]` snippet editor and add relevant HTML. Likely you want `$(this).closest("div")`

Comment: Can you show your html as well . If possible post on snippet .